# How to demonstrate the order of convergence of FTBS method for solving a hyperbolic PDE

Tags: pde, finite-difference, education

consider the Purely hyperbolic model problem
$$u_t+au_x=0$$
$$u(-1,t)=u(1,t) \text{ (periodic boundary)}$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

with $f(y)=\sin(2\pi y)$. Furthermore the exact solution is given by $u(x,t)=f(x-at)$. I have implemented **Forward–time backward–space** (see page 1: http://www.etakl.net/notes_etc/numerical/schemes.pdf ) on a uniform grid in time and space and the figure demonstrates my results with certain values of dt, dx and a.

**MY QUIESTION**: *How can I construct a test/example to **demonstrate the order of convergence**?* In theory the order of convergance should be 1 in time and 1 in space, right?
[image]

I am using the FDM book by LeVeque and this problem is from chapter 10.
I am using Python and I will be happy to share my code if needed. Thanks

Comment: If anyone else ever stumble upon this question, feel free to drop a comment at ask! I did solve it after getting help from nicoguaro♦ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refine your discretization and then compare the logarithm of the error ($\log |e|$) with the logarithm of the size ($\log h$) of your elements. Using a linear regression you could obtain an approximation of the order of convergence. Keep in mind that this order of convergence is asymptotic when $h \rightarrow 0$, so, for "large" $h$ you could see a different behavior.

Comment: But when I change my step size in time (dt) to compute the errors, do I need to keep step size in space (dx) constant?

Comment: No, that would make your scheme unstable.

Comment: And how should I measure the error? Should I take difference between my method and the exact solution at every gridpoint (in time and space) and define the error as the sum of them all?

Comment: You could sample your analytical solution and then compute the $L_2$ norm of the difference.

Comment: Is this what is meant by L2? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html . I can't seem to produce a linear loglog plot to allign with theory. Is it necessary to keep $C_r$ constant?

Comment: Yes, that's the $L_2$ norm. Feel free to share a link to the plot here or to create a chat room.

Comment: Instead of taking the the $L_2$ I took the the infinity norm and it worked! Thanks. I get descent convergent plots in both dt and dx (linear in a log log plot) Thank!